# Tipsy plugin don't work if detect change

Tags: jquery, html, woocommerce

I use Tipsy Jquery plugin and it work good, but only when I refresh the page.
I use Woocommerce too and in the cart page I have a select list for choose the shipping method. If I switch from one option to another and then I hover over the div which contain the Tipsy text it stops working until if I refresh the page.

The HTML :

```
<a href="#" rel="tipOrgTitle" original-title="Some text <strong>Other text</strong>.........">
```

The Jquery :

```
$('a[rel="tipOrgTitle"]').tipsy({
    html: true,
    opacity: 1,
    fade: true,
    title: function() { return this.getAttribute('original-title') }
});
```

It seems that if Tipsy detect some dynamique change on the page, it'll not  work until I refresh the page

Any help would be appreciated